# Update all fields in SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I rarely use SQL and have a unique issue I need to solve. I have a table called "j17_users" with various columns, two of which are "name" and "username". There are hundreds of rows of data.

I need to change the contents of "name" to be the same as "username"

For example, before:

```
name: Jon Smith
username: sql_nub
```

after:

```
name: Sql_nub
username: sql_nub
```

OK, so some of you may have noticed that the first letter has changed to uppercase in the above example. Bonus points if I could get that to happen in the script as well. If it's not possible than so be it..

Comment: This is solved by a basic SQL query, what is the difficulty ? Why is your question is PHP tagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capitalize the first:

```
UPDATE j17_users SET name = CONCAT(UCASE(MID(username,1,1)),MID(username,2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Now where are those "Bonus points" you mentioned? :P jk

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
Update j17_users set name = username
```

Comment: that works, had a few peeps point out how to capitalise as well. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
update YOURTABLENAME set name=username
```

I am no mysql expert, but I would look into a function that would grab the leftmost character (in MS SQL Server it is the "LEFT" function, provide argument length of 1), uppercase it (in MSSQLServer the function is called UPPER), then append it to the rest of the username field. If no one gives you the answer for that (which I doubt), look for the corresponding functions in MySQL and update the query above.

So MS SQL Server query would approximately look like the following:

```
UPDATE YOURTABLENAME set name = UPPER(LEFT(username, 1)) + RIGHT(username, LEN(username)-1)
```

Comment: "The right function requires 2 argument(s)" -  You need to remove the " 1," from the right function. I can't do this as an edit because edits need to be at least 6 characters...

Comment: Thanks, this was more of a general idea though, the person who asked the question was not going to use the statement anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for setting a field to another fields value

```
Update j17users set name = username
```

Comment: that works, had a few peeps point out how to capitalise as well. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL I would use.  It's pretty explicit

```
UPDATE j17_users SET name = 'sql_nub' WHERE name='John Smith'
```

OR a bit less explicit

```
UPDATE j17_users SET name = username WHERE name='John Smith'
```

Comment: not quite what I was looking for .. never mind though it has been answered

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
UPDATE j17_users set name = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(username, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(username, 2))) where name not like username;
```

Comment: Cheers pal, that works as well. Although there is a catch - it will not capitalise names if username is already the same (like is case insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

```
Update j17_users set name = 
CONCAT(UCASE(Left(username,1)),Right(username,Length(username)-1))
```